# buy another ones / buy the other ones

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Which phrase is common in this case? I know that "another one" is additional/different one when there are some ones (more than two). So, I think the first version is more common. The second version says only about two possibilities for choosing. Right?

> Don’t buy these headphones, **buy another ones**.
>
> Don’t buy these headphones, **buy the other ones**.

Comment: Say "different ones" and "the others".  Your understanding of the meaning is correct.

Comment: What's the context? Are there only two choices for headphones or many choices?

Comment: @gotube, there is no context. I'm trying to understand all versions.

Comment: @Sergey There's always a context. If you say, "*buy the other ones*" when there's only two choices, then it makes sense: "Don't buy these. Buy those". But if you're in a store where there's lots of other choices, it means "*Buy every other pair of headphones in the store.*" So I can't answer your question until I know the context. If you want to know the answer for all contexts, then your question isn't focused enough

Comment: @gotube, Context: 1) it's happening in a shop. 2) The last word in the sentence should be "ones".

Comment: Then, "*Buy some other ones*" is the most natural. "Another ones" is ungrammatical (as the-baby-is-you explains below).

Comment: @Sergey You mention that the sentence has to end with the word "ones," which suggests that this is a question in a test or exercise. To simplify it, "another ones" is not a good choice (as shown by the-baby-is-you). There are many good choices: "other ones," "different ones," "some other ones"—even, yes, "the other ones" if context has narrowed the focus to two (e.g. out of a store of hundreds, you've been discussing two models). "Buy *any* other ones!", maybe.

Comment: @Andy Bonner, Why do you think that this question is from a test or exercise? I wrote before that I'm trying to understand all versions. I do my self-education in English. Is it a problem? Why is there a need to find something illegal?

Comment: @Sergey No need for concern; I just thought the requirement to end the sentence with a certain word suggests an external framework. If you don't have to end with "ones," then personally I'd say "Don't buy these, buy those."

Comment: @Andy Bonner, Such a simple sentence is not a problem for me. Today, I'm learning "ones".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Another" is always singular. Despite how its usage has drifted, it still grammatically functions like the two-word phrase it's derived from, "an other": singular article "an", i.e. one. With a plural noun like headphones, we have to construct the sentence differently.

"The other ones" of course has a definite article, so it would be used only if there was one other specific pair that was obviously being referred to. As long as that's the case, "the other ones" would be perfectly valid and idiomatic.

To have the same meaning as "another one", you'd usually say "another pair", "another set", or the like. You could also say "different ones" (more directly "other ones", but that wouldn't be very idiomatic in this context) or "some other ones", but usually only if the other options aren't predetermined (you'd look for "some other ones" online or in the store down the street, but not with five choices in front of you).

You might be able to get away with "don't buy these headphones, buy another one", in which it would be understood that you had implicitly switched the subject halfway through. Native speakers might well do this in a poorly-planned sentence, but it wouldn't be regarded as good English.

Comment: Why isn't "different ones"  idiomatic in this context?

Comment: @Sergey "Different ones" is fine, "other ones" is just a little off. There's not really a good reason why.